# C# .NET Charts Libraries/Code?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, charts, ms-office

I am creating some reporting software that will generate excel workbooks with charts and all related data. Besides the built in libraries and .NET Office integration features, is there any other tools or code that people found useful to creating similar projects?

EDIT: I am targeting winforms.

Comment: As Gigasoft's founder, research and compare to those listed below. See our no-hassle small 18 meg download [.Net Charting Library Demo](http://www.gigasoft.com). The demo is condensed research easy to assimilate. Includes EXEs based on WinForms, Wpf, and MFC for comparison. Charts in reports must behave the best as user interaction is often not available to tweak an ugly chart.  Gigasoft has always prioritized artificial intelligence logic to maintain image quality independent on properties, configuration, size, and shape. Size our demo to compare.

Answer (score 7):

I've used [ZedGraph](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) before, and I found it pretty good for a free library.

Comment: Yeah, ZedGraph is a nice library.

Comment: agreed. its great and I've used it in my personal project (stochfit.sourceforge.net) if you need an example. The only downside is that its no longer maintained, and there are a couple of irritating bugs in it. I've fixed them in my personal branch, but there is no one maintaining the project.

Answer (score 5):

If you are not already aware... Microsoft released these free charting controls for .NET

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[SpreadSheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/)  I never used it but it is advertised a lot

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Reporting Services.

Answer (score 2):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is an Excel compatible spreadsheet component for .NET that supports spreadsheet features as well as Excel compatible charting. You did not specify whether you are targeting WinForms or ASP.NET, but SpreadsheetGear can be used with both.

You can see a live chart gallery with charts being rendered by SpreadsheetGear [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/chartgallery.aspx) and download the evaluation software [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with the [Office Open XML  Library](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=127912) ([portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx)), which allows you to create Excel files without Office interop.   Its a little hard to learn, since you have to learn the underlying document format, and Version 2.0 is still in CTP until Office14 comes out, but its a fast (performant) and free solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Steema TeeChart.Net](http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/net/overview.html). It is a very powerful chart but it is not free and not cheap (Around $760 per developer).

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion](http://syncfusion.com/products/back-office/xlsio) has a native .NET utility that allows for spreadsheet automation (including charting capabilities) without going through Excel.

The bundle isn't cheap or easy to use, but it is powerful.