# display charts using asp.net

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-3.5, graph

I have developed a GUI using ASP.NET 3.5 and C#....

Now at some places i need to display the data using graphs like pie or bar...

I need to know how to start to do this...As in i was going through Crystal Reports, the there was something about MS charts...i need to know where can i read the tutorial and then implement it in my GUI...

I also like to know the Licence type.. i am looking for something that is free to try and distribute..

Thanks

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064208/c-net-charts-libraries-code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS charts, yes. [They're free](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)

[And ScottGu introduces them here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) (with links to documentation)

Comment: so what would recommend... MS charts or Crystal reports... or is there any other free control... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ZedGraph (http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) is another one - with sourcecode.

I'm using it in many Projects.

Comment: is it free?? but i herd it is not maintained anymore...??

Comment: Yes - it's free. LGPL Licence. Where did you herd that's not maintained anymore? OK, last release was Dec 2008 (soureforge files). Is there a statement?

Answer (score 0):

I can really recommend going for a third party library like Infragistics or Dundas. They are not that expensive and give you much richer functionality.

Comment: i checked out these company softwares.. though they look amazing to me i still need to go with something that is free to try and distribute... Can u help me there..